# Incluir arquivo em projeto Java

Tags: java, ssh

Tenho um codigo que executa rotinas dentro de servidores Linux e faço acesso utilizando chaves publicas.
Quando o projeto esta em meu pc (desenvolvimento), tudo funciona pois no código eu especifico o local da chave que esta em minha maquina, porem ao gerar um jar (package for store) e executar em outro computador, o programa não acha essa chave.

Ja coloquei a chave dentro da pasta src/meuProjeto e fiz a referencia ao arquivo e localmente funcionou, porem em outra maquina não.

Pesquisei sobre getresources mas mesmo assim não consegui.

Faço referencia ao arquivo como uma string qualquer:

```
String privateKey = "Diretorio\id_dsa.ppk";
```

Qual seria a forma correta de anexar essa chave junto ao meu projeto para que seja executada em qualquer maquina?

Answer (score 1):

Voce está fazendo referencia ao diretório via hard coded, isto não é uma boa ideia, em ambientes diferentes isso pode não funcionar, por exemplo, o Windows usa a famigerada "barra invertida" para separar diretórios, já o linux usa a "barra normal".

### [Yaml](http://yaml.org/)

A boa prática nesse caso é a utilização de um arquivo de configuração, minha preferencia é o [yaml](http://yaml.org/), algumas linguagens, como python, tem pacotes para parse de yaml, não sei se tem em java, mas [tem esse tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/read-yaml-in-java-with-jackson).

Exemplo de um arquivo de configuração yaml:

```
linux:
  privateKey: /home/user/keys/id_dsa.ppk  
  ...

windows:
  privateKey: c:\path\keys\id_dsa.ppk
```

Então em sua app basta identificar o ambiente e ler a variável da privatekey a partir da chave correta (linux ou windows).

### [Variável de ambiente:](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc668471.aspx)

Outra opção dentro das boas práticas é o uso de variáveis de ambiente. A sua app teria que ler uma variável de ambiente que aponte o caminho do arquivo, exemplo de criação das variáveis:

Criando variável de ambiente no linux:

```
export PKEY=/home/user/keys/id_dsa.ppk
```

Para criar variáveis de ambiente no windows, [veja esse link](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc668471.aspx).

**Obs.:**
 
A utilização das variáveis de ambiente pode parecer mais fácil para o lado desenvolvedor, mas, na minha opinião, o arquivo de configuração é mais seguro e flexivel.